# string.replace returns Uncaught TypeError: link.Replace is not a function

Tags: javascript

I checked other questions and they didn't helped me.

```
var link = $('div.slide[data-index='+i+'] img').attr('src');
console.log(link);
console.log(typeof(link));
link = link.Replace("t23","");
```

In console:

```
http://***.com/photos/test-photo_16x9.jpg
string
Uncaught TypeError: link.Replace is not a function
```

I don't understand, why I cannot use replace on a string? What happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace in lower case, not "Replace" in capital.

Answer (score 1):

You did replace with a uppercase R it's

```
var link = $('div.slide[data-index='+i+'] img').attr('src');
console.log(link);
console.log(typeof(link));
link = link.replace("t23","");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var link = $('div.slide[data-index='+i+'] img').attr('src');
console.log(link);
console.log(typeof(link));
link = link.replace("t23","");
```

Description: Replaced 'Replace' with 'replace'.